# select permission was denied on the object 'sysjobs'

Tags: sql-server-2008, permissions

```
The select permission was denied on the object 'sysjobs', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'.
```

I have already tried to grant `sqlagentoperatorrole` and it didn't work. How do I resolve this error?

Comment: I have the same issue and tried already the steps outlined in the MSDN link. It doesn't work. Is there any restrictions on how this should work on SQL 2008 R2?

Answer (score 5):

You use the ["SQL Server Agent Fixed Database Roles"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188283.aspx) in msdb (MSDN link).

And a "how to" for SSMS: ["How to: Configure a User to Create and Manage SQL Server Agent Jobs (SQL Server Management Studio)"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187901.aspx)

Note: you need a [*user* (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337545.aspx) in one of these roles: no need to GRANT rights to sqlagentoperator